# Cannot add div element with styling on window load using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to append div to body when it's loaded. So far the [solution](http://embed.plnkr.co/he97059ddnsebJFPW7eI/preview) does not work. How to fix it?

The actual code:

```
window.onload = function(){
  alert('hi');
    var element = document.createElement('div');
    element.style.backgroundImage = "http://hqwallbase.com/images/big/sunny-1551869.jpg";
    document.body.appendChild(element);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
element.style.backgroundImage = "url(http://hqwallbase.com/images/big/sunny-1551869.jpg)";
```

---

<kbd>**[Updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IJzNpWHkaR1cAijqAjRL?p=preview)**</kbd>

You also have to specify the `width` and `height`.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var element = document.createElement('div');
  element.style.backgroundImage = "url(http://s25.postimg.org/od0ktijyn/sunny_1551869.jpg)";
  element.style.backgroundSize = '100% 100%';
  element.style.width = '100%';
  element.style.height = '1000px';
  document.body.appendChild(element);
};
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```
alert('hi');
var element = document.createElement('div');
element.style.backgroundImage = "url(http://hqwallbase.com/images/big/sunny-1551869.jpg)";
element.style.border = '1px solid red';
element.style.height = '300px';
document.body.appendChild(element);
```

Check images if it is available and given url or use another image.

Answer (score 0):

Shyam's solution won't work outside of a function. Plus, you don't need to style your element via JS: you can do it via CSS (if you add an id or CSS class to your element). Based on Shyam's solution, I propose the following:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  var element = document.createElement('div');
  element.setAttribute("id", "myID");
  document.body.appendChild(element);
});
```

```css
#myID {
  background: url('http://hqwallbase.com/images/big/sunny-1551869.jpg') no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 300px;
}
```